xcrysden install and run on edubuntu 2024 but not open
I recently installed edubuntu 24.04.l on my HP Pavilion laptop and I was planning to install and use xcrysden, but after a successful installation via the terminal by sudo apt-get install, I encountered the following error:
Package Xwd: /usr/bin/xwd
Executing: /usr/lib/xcrysden/ftnunit
Error in startup script: 
Couldn't configure togl widget
    while executing
"togl .mesa  -width          400  -height         400  -ident          .mesa  -rgba           $toglOpt(rgba)           -redsize        $toglOpt(redsize..."
    (procedure "PlaceGlobWin" line 107)
    invoked from within
"PlaceGlobWin 0 [expr round(670 * $fac1)] [expr round(670 * $fac1)]"
    (procedure "ViewMol" line 25)
    invoked from within
"ViewMol ."
    invoked from within
"if { [llength $argv] > 2 } {
    parseComLinArg [lrange $argv 2 end]
} else {
    ViewMol .
}"
    (file "/usr/share/xcrysden/Tcl/xcInit.tcl" line 633)
my kernel information by "uname -a" command is
Linux sh 6.8.0-51-generic #52-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Dec  5 13:09:44 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
and for
lspci -k
Host bridge: Intel Corporation Raptor Lake-P/U 2p+8e cores Host Bridge/DRAM Controller (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Raptor Lake-P/U 2p+8e cores Host Bridge/DRAM Controller
    Kernel driver in use: igen6_edac
    Kernel modules: igen6_edac
VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Raptor Lake-P [Iris Xe Graphics] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Raptor Lake-P [Iris Xe Graphics]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915, xe
Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Raptor Lake Dynamic Platform and Thermal Framework Processor Participant (rev 01)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Raptor Lake Dynamic Platform and Thermal Framework Processor Participant
    Kernel driver in use: proc_thermal_pci
    Kernel modules: processor_thermal_device_pci
 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Raptor Lake PCIe 4.0 Graphics Port (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Raptor Lake PCIe 4.0 Graphics Port
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
 System peripheral: Intel Corporation GNA Scoring Accelerator module (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company GNA Scoring Accelerator module
 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Raptor Lake Crashlog and Telemetry (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Raptor Lake Crashlog and Telemetry
    Kernel driver in use: intel_vsec
    Kernel modules: intel_vsec
 USB controller: Intel Corporation Raptor Lake-P Thunderbolt 4 USB Controller (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Raptor Lake-P Thunderbolt 4 USB Controller
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
    Kernel modules: xhci_pci
 Serial controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P Integrated Sensor Hub (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Alder Lake-P Integrated Sensor Hub
    Kernel driver in use: intel_ish_ipc
    Kernel modules: intel_ish_ipc
 USB controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH USB 3.2 xHCI Host Controller (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Alder Lake PCH USB 3.2 xHCI Host Controller
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
    Kernel modules: xhci_pci
 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH Shared SRAM (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Alder Lake PCH Shared SRAM
Network controller: Intel Corporation Raptor Lake PCH CNVi WiFi (rev 01)
    DeviceName: WLAN
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Raptor Lake PCH CNVi WiFi
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Alder Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci
 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Alder Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci
 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH HECI Controller (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Alder Lake PCH HECI Controller
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me
    Kernel modules: mei_me
 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Alder Lake-P Serial IO I2C Controller
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci
 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Alder Lake-P Serial IO I2C Controller
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci
 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P PCH PCIe Root Port #4 (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Alder Lake-P PCH PCIe Root Port
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH UART #0 (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Alder Lake PCH UART
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci
 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake SPI Controller (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Alder Lake SPI Controller
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci
 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Raptor Lake LPC/eSPI Controller (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Raptor Lake LPC/eSPI Controller
 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Raptor Lake-P/U/H cAVS (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Raptor Lake-P/U/H cAVS
    Kernel driver in use: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl
 SMBus: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH-P SMBus Host Controller (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Alder Lake PCH-P SMBus Host Controller
    Kernel driver in use: i801_smbus
    Kernel modules: i2c_i801
 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P PCH SPI Controller (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Alder Lake-P PCH SPI Controller
    Kernel driver in use: intel-spi
    Kernel modules: spi_intel_pci
 Non-Volatile memory controller: Phison Electronics Corporation PS5013-E13 PCIe3 NVMe Controller (DRAM-less) (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Phison Electronics Corporation PS5013-E13 PCIe3 NVMe Controller (DRAM-less)
    Kernel driver in use: nvme
    Kernel modules: nvme
 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 5228 (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 8bf6
    Kernel driver in use: rtsx_pci
    Kernel modules: rtsx_pci

When I tried Ubuntu 20.04 the xcrysden package was easily installed and started, but for some reason this problem has arisen in Ubuntu 24.04 Can anyone guide me to solve it?
